# Phrase for trusting someone untrustworthy again?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Consider a situation which you trust your friend for 35th times although he failed in previous 34 time!

You are saying to your self I'm such a fool that do this again.

What's the phrase for describing this situation?

Comment: If you do so consciously you could say graciously trust

Comment: It's similar to *throwing good money after bad,* but that's only used for spending money to keep something going.

Comment: a fool's errand, a hopeless task.

Comment: From a "criminology and penology" perspective, you can refer to this foolish mistake of yours as "recidivism". The wikipedia meaning of this word is the following ---------------  "Recidivism (/rᵻˈsɪdᵻvɪzəm/; from recidive and ism, from Latin recidīvus "recurring", from re- "back" and cadō "I fall") is the act of a person repeating an undesirable behavior after they had either experienced negative consequences of that behavior.

Comment: One phrase for this is "a triumph of hope over experience", normally used when someone marries for the umpteenth time.

Comment: I guess I’ll never learn...

Comment: I'm giving his another chance?

Comment: Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me twice, shame on me. Fool me thirty-five times...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote "The definition of insanity is doing something over and over again and expecting a different result" has been [attributed](http://www.news.hypercrit.net/2012/11/13/einstein-on-misattribution-i-probably-didnt-say-that/) to Albert Einstein. So *insanity* would describe your situation. :-)

Comment: Please read the long comment I wrote as a post

Comment: The counterargument is given by the Bible. *Peter asked Jesus how many times should he forgive his brother. Peter thought maybe seven times might be a fair limit. But Jesus said "seventy times seven"* (Matthew 18:21-22).  Biblical scholars will tell you that seven was used to represent a large number as there was no word for infinite.  I will point out that forgiveness is not the same thing as lending money....

Comment: Fine. That's what I used to believe when was young.

Comment: Just presenting both sides of the argument. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a word for this in Persian which is translated to stupidity but according to this quote of Einstein it's better to say insanity.
As a common example it refers to cows because they know that if they were fat they will killed but they eat like a stupid! I think it's better so say like a insane.

Insane is translated to something means mad or moron.